# Insert a charcater inside a 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, character, 2d

Hi I have 2 functions: one to create a 2d array of 10x15 and a second function to insert a character in a given slot inside the array.

```
void printTab(char tab[][15]);
void insertCharacter(int x, int y, char *letter, char tab[][15]);

int main() {
  char tab[10][15];

  insertCharacter(6, 6, 'x', tab);
  printTab(&tab);
  return 0;
}

void insertCharacter(int x, int y, char *letter, char tab[][15]) {
  tab[x][y] = car;
}

void printTab(char tab[][15]) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {

      printf(" ");
    }
  }
}
```

As an aside question: should I initialize the 2d array first and then print it out or is it ok to do all this in one function ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate question. I got rid of the segmentation fault. But I still cannot insert a character into the array.

Comment: Try to read your warning/error ? https://ideone.com/oZOpbV. By the way you should not fix your question.

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/6bd2B2)

Comment: `printTab(&tab);` --> `printTab(tab);`, `char *letter` --> `char letter`, `car` --> `letter`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you for your help. and sorry for the duplicate question on segmentation fault.